# Error only when I'm NOT in ~/.config/nvim directory

Tags: neovim, lua

I get this error when I open nvim in any directory other than `~/.config/nvim`

```
Error detected while processing /home/evirac/.config/nvim/init.lua: E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: /home/evirac/.config/nvim/init.lua:1: module 'keymaps' not found:
```

It works fine when I'm in nvim directory. It works even when I open any other directory given that I am in nvim directory

```
evirac@fedora ~/.c/nvim> ls

init.lua keymaps.lua pack/ plugin/ plugins.lua
```

> init.lua

```
require('keymaps')

require('plugins')
```

The plugins work in other directories though. (I only have one plugin rn)

Comment: @Prem let's keep answers out of comments and comments on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move the two files:

- `keymaps.lua`
- `plugins.lua`

Into the `~/.config/nvim/lua` folder (that it seems that you have to create first).
That `lua` is a special folder from which Neovim can import (`requier` Lua packages).

Comment: yeah this works

Comment: Welcome to Vim! Thanks for the feedback. Maybe could you approve the solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: I'd gladly have already done it  but I need 15+ rep points which I don't have

Comment: To validate a solution using the v button you should not have any point requirement. I have voted your question maybe it helps to give your the point you need ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the vote. I misled you. The button is not to validate the solution but to **accept** the solution. It is done using the v button bellow the **Save this answer** button.